# validate against an ActiveDirectory group of WCF caller in the server side

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, nettcpbinding, windows-identity

I have a WCF service, hosted in a WindowService, using nettcpbinding in which I want to perform check in the C# code if the sender belongs to a specific AD group.

Is it possible? if so, how?

Comment: It is possible but the implementation depends on the application topology (for example, how is the service hosted: IIS, Windows Service, Console application e.t.c., is the client accessing the service in the same network/domain, is the windows authentication Kerberos or NTLM e.t.c.).

Comment: @lonut Ungureanu -  WindowsService (updated the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming that the WCF client and server are on the same domain, you could do something like that:

On the client side, you allow using the windows identity to authenticate the client:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
....
ServiceReference.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;
```

On the server side, you retrive the caller windows identity and test if it belongs to the group:

```
    WindowsIdentity callerWindowsIdentity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;
    WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(callerWindowsIdentity);
    var isInRole = windowsPrincipal.IsInRole("Users");
```